How to hide text over image in responsive when I scroll?
I'm developing a webpage featuring text on the right and an accompanying image on the left. As users scroll, the image dynamically adjusts based on the associated text. While the layout functions smoothly on desktop, I'm facing challenges in responsive.
In responsive design, the image is displayed above the text, which is correct. However, I can see the words above the image as I scroll. How do I fix this? See attachment.
The code I'm working with is shown below:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const artwork = document.getElementById('artwork');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.content-section');

    const transformations = [
        { scale: 1, translateX: 0, translateY: 0 },        // Section 1
        { scale: 2.2, translateX: 60, translateY: -30 },   // Section 2
        { scale: 1.9, translateX: -30, translateY: -150 }, //section 3
        { scale: 2, translateX: -130, translateY: -200 }   // Section 4
    ];

    const scrollHandler = () => {
        const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2;

        sections.forEach((section, index) => {
            const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
            const sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

            if (scrollPosition > sectionTop && scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
                const transform = transformations[index];
                artwork.style.transform = `scale(${transform.scale}) translate(${transform.translateX}px, ${transform.translateY}px)`;
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    scrollHandler(); // Initial call to set the correct transform on load
});
.imscroll {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.interactive-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    height: 180vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-section {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

     .interactive-container {
        height: 40vh;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .interactive-container img {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40vh;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .interactive-container {
        z-index: 2; /* Increase z-index */
    }
}
<div class="imscroll">
<div class="grid-test">
<div class="interactive-container">
<p><img src="http://www.reedyrace.com/images/b64d-chassis.jpg" alt="Artwork" id="artwork" style=" border: 1px solid gray;" /></p>
</div>

<div class="text-section" style=" padding-left: 20px;">
<section class="content-section" id="section1">
<h2 style=" margin-top: 0;">Section 1 (No Zoom)</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section2">
<h2>Zoom to Left Side</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section3">
<h2>Zoom to Battery</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section4">
<h2>Zoom to Right Bottom</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>




top: -20px; instead of top: 20px; solves the problem according to my tests:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const artwork = document.getElementById('artwork');
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.content-section');

    const transformations = [
        { scale: 1, translateX: 0, translateY: 0 },        // Section 1
        { scale: 2.2, translateX: 60, translateY: -30 },   // Section 2
        { scale: 1.9, translateX: -30, translateY: -150 }, //section 3
        { scale: 2, translateX: -130, translateY: -200 }   // Section 4
    ];

    const scrollHandler = () => {
        const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight / 2;

        sections.forEach((section, index) => {
            const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
            const sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

            if (scrollPosition > sectionTop && scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
                const transform = transformations[index];
                artwork.style.transform = `scale(${transform.scale}) translate(${transform.translateX}px, ${transform.translateY}px)`;
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
    scrollHandler(); // Initial call to set the correct transform on load
});
.imscroll {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.text-section {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.interactive-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: -20px;
    height: 180vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

.interactive-container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.content-section {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Responsive Design */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .grid-test {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

     .interactive-container {
        height: 40vh;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .interactive-container img {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40vh;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .interactive-container {
        z-index: 2; /* Increase z-index */
    }
}
<div class="imscroll">
<div class="grid-test">
<div class="interactive-container">
<p><img src="http://www.reedyrace.com/images/b64d-chassis.jpg" alt="Artwork" id="artwork" style=" border: 1px solid gray;" /></p>
</div>

<div class="text-section" style=" padding-left: 20px;">
<section class="content-section" id="section1">
<h2 style=" margin-top: 0;">Section 1 (No Zoom)</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section2">
<h2>Zoom to Left Side</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section3">
<h2>Zoom to Battery</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>

<section class="content-section" id="section4">
<h2>Zoom to Right Bottom</h2>

<p>Paragraph1 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</div>



